# Laravel - Sendgrid smtp error "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed"

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am following [Sendgrid laravel integration using smtp](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/laravel.html) to send email.

I did as the documentation says, all credentials are same as my sendgrid credentials.

But whenever I try to send email using,

```
Mail::send('mails.demo', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'test')->subject('This is a test mail!');
        });
```

It shows error as

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
"
```

I can send email using sendgrid test using [Telnet guide](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Troubleshooting/Delivery_Issues/testing_your_connectivity_to_sendgrids_smtp_relay_using_telnet.html), that works perfectly.

Comment: your "from" address should match with the smtp configurations in conf/mail.php.

Comment: Can you post your config file, with credentials obscured?

Comment: Does the "from" address you are using match a registered "from" address at sendgrid?

Comment: @yivi I am using verified from email(we have only one email for that)

Answer (score 1):

`"550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed"` explicitly means that you're system is not attempting to Authenticate. So you're not actually sending your credentials through. You should review your Laravel configuration, and make sure that it will send the `AUTH` command before sending the `MAIL FROM:` command.

Answer (score 1):

you should create Sender Identity and verify.
or if  you use a domain you should verify your domain

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue in my team and once I check with developer, developer added sendgrid credentials both in **.env** file and **config/mail.php** file.

May be same issue happening there, if so revert the **config/mail.php** with the one created in laravel installation.