# Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed " in SendGrid

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, sendgrid

Please I am trying to send verification email on my laravel app, it work with mailtrap, but I can't send to the user email, so I want to use sendgrid

Here is my details in my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587   
MAIL_USERNAME=sendgridlogin
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgridpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In my mail config file, I have this

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'sendgrid'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'example@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('sendgridlogin'),

    'password' => env('sendgridpassword'),

.
.
```

But it returned error

**Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
 "**

Please, I have checked other questions, I can't seems to figure it out. I have clear cache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Sendgrid smtp error "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393632/laravel-sendgrid-smtp-error-550-unauthenticated-senders-not-allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR APIKEY'
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=yoursendgridusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=yoursendgridpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=myname
```

I also added this to force SSL locally in my mail.php

> Don't use this in production

```
'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
           'allow_self_signed' => true,
           'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
     ],
```

Don't forget to update your mail.php with sendgrid details.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Unauthenticated Senders not allowed" explicitly means that you're not attempting to authenticate into the SendGrid environment. So even though you're defining your username & password, your connection is not actually sending across the `AUTH LOGIN` step of the SMTP transaction.

Comment: Yes this error comes when we are trying to send email from not authorized email from your sendgrid account. Firstly we need to define that email in sendgrid account then this email will be able to be used on sending email.