# Sendgrid 550 unauthenticated senders not allowed laravel swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, smtp, sendgrid

When I'm using SendGrid to send email in Laravel, it results in the following error:

> "550 unauthenticated senders not allowed"

I couldn't find out why this happens. So far, I've configured sender authentication from SendGrid account and created an API key, which is used as a password and username as apikey.

I've also tried with the same set of credentials (username and password) from SendGrid, but this also didn't work.

My .env file sets these mail parameters:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=API Key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="text.com"
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jasie I don't have any code to show. When we initially start laravel project there are some commands to make authentication functionality. Then I changed in .env file. In .env file simply set mail parameters

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=API Key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="text.com"

Comment: You should move these settings into the question, they do not belong into a comment.

Comment: @jasie I have moved this settings to comment so please answer me if you know. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this? https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/smtp-errors-and-troubleshooting/#550-unauthenticated-senders-not-allowed

Comment: Did you check the other questions on StackOverflow, containing the very same sendgrid error messages?

Comment: @jasie Yes checked all this things but nothing happens for me.

Answer (score 0):

> "If you’re getting an “Unauthenticated Senders Not Allowed” error, the
>   problem usually lies in authenticating with our SMTP server. This
>   error gets triggered when there was an attempt to hand over an email
>   message through smtp.sendgrid.net before authenticating the connection
>   with your SendGrid username and password."

From the docu at https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/smtp-errors-and-troubleshooting/#550-unauthenticated-senders-not-allowed

So check this:

- make sure that you’ve configured your setup to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net using authentication
- make sure that the credentials you’re using are the same credentials you
  use to login to the SendGrid

Repeat the steps described at https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/authentication/#api-key-recommended
and at https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/

Replace 'apikey' and 'API Key' in your .env file by the SendGrid username and SendGrid password that you set.

Comment: "make sure that you’ve configured your setup to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net using authentication" What do you mean by this line how can i configured my setup to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net using authentication?

Comment: The second and third link in my answer explain exactly this.

Comment: I still not getting solution and don't understand what is the meaning of "make sure that you’ve configured your setup to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net using authentication"

Till what i have done is 
Create an account on sendgrid. Then in .env and config/mail.php file I changed  details same as 
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sendgrid_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgrid_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Smith"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com

then sending mail show me error "550 unauthenticated senders not allowed".

Comment: Most likely, your sendgrid username or your sendgrid password are not entered correctly in your .env file.

Comment: using same username and password

Comment: also, check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393632/laravel-sendgrid-smtp-error-550-unauthenticated-senders-not-allowed

Comment: laravel 5.7 ,  PHP 7.3 , Sendgrid is implement direclty by laravel we have just set configuration in config mail.php and .env file

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393632/laravel-sendgrid-smtp-error-550-unauthenticated-senders-not-allowed" not helpful